# Django REST Framework: How to add a foreign primary key to an M2M serializer that uses a through table?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

> **How can I add a primary key from a M2M relationship to my serializer?**

The examples I have seen only seem to work when a custom through model isn't set.

models:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Order(models.Model):
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(Inventory, through='myapp.OrderItem')
    ...

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory)
    sell_price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

serializers:

```
class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ('id', )

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    inventory_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='inventory.id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('order_id', 'inventory_id', 'sell_price', 'quantity',)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    inventory_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='inventory.id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

Expected Results:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "order_items": [
            {
                "inventory_id": 1,
                "sell_price": "2.00",
                "quantity": 12
            },
            {
                "inventory_id": 2,
                "sell_price": "9.50",
                "quantity": 6
            },
            {
                "inventory_id": 3,
                "sell_price": "77.77",
                "quantity": 1
            }

... <other fields>

],
```

Ive tried various combinations of field names in meta, adding the `InventorySerializer` directly to the model, etc. but I can't seem to get it to work.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order_item` attribute of your `Order` model is a list of instances of `Inventory` model. Regardless of your custom M2M through table definition, the query look up via `order_item` attribute is going to return `Inventory` instances instead of your desired `OrderItem` instances.

One possible way to obtain the output in your desired format can be as follows -

```py
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('order_id', 'inventory_id', 'sell_price', 'quantity',)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_order_items(self, instance):
        order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=instance)
        return OrderItemSerializer(order_items, many=True).data
```